# How do I display the next 3 dates from today in a particular format in php?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am trying to print out the next 3 days from today. This code works fine but I need the dates to be in this format "2018 Sept, 29". Changing format keeps giving me errors.

```
<?php
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('AFRICA/LAGOS');

// Start date
$date = date('Y-m-d');
// End date
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $date=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
    echo $date.', ';
}
echo "<br><br>";
?>
```

Comment: What "errors" are you getting?

Comment: I get this error when i change the format to format('Y M, d');" Call to a member function modify() on boolean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it with `date()` and `for()` loop:-

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('AFRICA/LAGOS');

$date = date('Y-m-d');
for($i =1;$i<=3;$i++){
  echo $end_date = date('Y M,d', strtotime("+$i days"));
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/YXZEe

A bit functional approach:

```
<?php

function getNextDatesFromCurrentDate($how_many_dates){
    date_default_timezone_set('AFRICA/LAGOS');

    for($i =1;$i<=$how_many_dates;$i++){
        echo $end_date = date('Y M,d', strtotime("+$i days"));
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}

getNextDatesFromCurrentDate(3);
```

https://3v4l.org/1vKVA

Comment: This works perfectly, i guess i was just over thinking it. Thanks so much

Comment: @nellytadi  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Carbon library, to Add days
Like , 
$date = Carbon::today();
$nextday = $date->addDay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PHP [date format documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), you can print the name of the month in english with `format('Y-F-d')`

Or you can make your own function which returns the name of the month with the number you provide.

Answer (score 0):

To add number of dates to particular date. you need to pass two parameters to `strtotime()` function.

1.number of days

2.starting date

and to format to '2018 sept, 29' you need to give the correct format to `date('Y M, d')` function.

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d');
$dates = collect();
foreach (range(1,3) as $number_of_days) {
    $dates->push(date('Y M, d', strtotime("+$number_of_days days", strtotime($start_date))));
}
```